# How to customise what URL ember-data requests for a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ember.js, controller, ember-data

My use case is quite simple, I have an invite system that allowes users to be invited and sign up. This is using a EmberJS, Ember-Data and Ruby on Rails stack.

```
MyEmberApp.InviteRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', { invitation_token: params.token }).then(function(array) {
        return array.get('firstObject');
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, user) {
    controller.set('model', user);
  }
});
```

The object loads fine and is perfect.

However, here's what my Rails controller looks like:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :system_admin, only: [:index, :create]

  def index
    if params[:invitation_token]
      load_invited_user
      render json: @user
    else
      load_users
      render json: @users
    end
  end
end
```

I want an **unauthenticated** user to be able to accept the invitation, and the ember route above will load the user using this controller. The code as is only works if a user is logged in and the `system_admin` before_action runs properly.

You see my problem?

How can I customise the ember route's URL to a separate action, so that I can explicitly set it to allow anonymous users?

Comment: I guess misunderstood what you wanted or I'm not expressing myself correctly. Watching this one

Comment: I'm not familiar with rails but [this is how you can customize the url](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_pathForType)